# FileNotFoundException while trying to access external storage Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, video-capture, ioexception

I am following the code sample at Android Developer guide for [capturing video](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) from my app. Things are pretty smooth until I invoke the `prepare` method on `MediaRecorder` instance. It throws an `IOException` with following message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/MyVideoFile.mp4: 
open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The code is pretty much the same as on the site. To summarize, there is:

- `CameraActivity` class for managing the Camera and MediaRecorder
  resources.
- `FileManager` class that returns a Uri for output file path to be used 
  for storing the video preview frames.

Code snippet:

```
public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) throws Exception {
        if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to access device SDCard.");
        }

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");

    if(! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if(! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(CameraActivity.MYAPP, "Failed to create directory.");
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name.
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath(),
        "MyAudioFile.jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath(),
        "MyVideoFile.mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

The `mediaFile` is passed as an argument to `_mediaRecorder.setOutputFile()` method. However, when I invoke `_mediaRecorder.prepare()`, it throws the `IOException`.

I have already included `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in AndroidManifest file.

The ***surprising point*** is that if I omit the `mediaRecorder.prepare` call and check the sdcard for presence of the file, it is there !! However, if I run the above code to completion and check back the folder, the file is not there. It appears the file is getting deleted by `_mediaRecorder.prepare` call !!

I am pretty new to Android development and have already spent over a day trying to figure this out. Any help will be greatly valued !!

Answer (score 3):

I've followed this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video example and had the same issue.

The problem there, was that the method to create the directory and construct the file name returned a File but later wrapped by another method which returned a Uri. The Uri added the "/file:" to the file path string. Passing the string returned by the URI to mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(..), made the prepare function call to throw an exception.

I fixed it by simply taking the video file and calling ToString() to get its path and pass it to mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(..);
Then prepare() worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator increase the SD Card space to 1024mb.
Also check if you are affected by this one: WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE
http://www.chainfire.eu/articles/113/Is_Google_blocking_apps_writing_to_SD_cards_/

Other: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/android-4.1.2_r2.1/AndroidManifest.xml